# A quotient module of a Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra. If $A$ and $B$ are $L$-submodules of an $L$-module $V$, such that $A\subset B$ and $I\cdot B\subset A$ for some ideal $A$ in $L$.

I want to understand why this implies that  $B/A$ is an $L/I$-module?

Comment: Do you understand why it is an L-module?

Comment: Then you should start with that...

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand your question, do you mean that $B/A$ is an $L$-module?

Comment: Indeed. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Yes it is by setting $x + \overline v=\overline{ x + v}$, where $\overline v $ denotes the coset v + W. and the space $V/W$ is called the quotient module of $ V$ and $W$.

Comment: I think you mixed up the sum with the action, but ok. Now: under that action, in the situation of your question, how do elements of the ideal I act on that quotient?

Comment: well, since $x\cdot B\subset A$ then $x\cdot (b+A)=(x\cdot b)+A=A$

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand why $I\cdot B/A=A$ implies B/A is an  L/I - module.. Any hints ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

- If $A$ and $B$ are $L$-modules then so is $B/A$. Do you know how $L$ acts on $B/A$?
- If $Q$ is an $L$-module, $I\trianglelefteq L$ an ideal and every element of $I$ acts as the zero map on $Q$, then $Q$ naturally becomes an $L/I$-module. Do you know how $L/I$ acts on $Q$?

After understanding both of these things, apply with $Q=B/A$.

Comment: The first action is $x.(b+A):=(x.b)+A$ ,, but the second action can we set it like $(x+I).q:=x.q$ which is well-defined since $(i+I).q=i.q=0$ for $i\in I$?

Comment: @Ronald Yes. ${}$